# how to show auto-increment number from database to jTextField java netbeans automatically

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.1 and phpmyadmin as database

I'm making a simple cashier application. In the receipt form, I want to make that receipt number and shown automatically from database when I run the application. It shows the newer number (increasing by 1) from the last receipt's number.

I've tried this code, but it still didn't work.

database:
[image: database]

code:

```
private void jTextFieldIActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        Connection koneksi = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/beli_barang", "root", "");
        ResultSet data = koneksi.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT MAX(no_kwit) FROM kwitansi");
        int dat = data.getInt(1);
        String a = "";
        a = Integer.toString(dat);
        jTextField1.setText(a);     
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Kwitansi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVER, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code in text format

Comment: Added images into the question. Please convert the code image into text.

Comment: @Rao thanks, I've changed the post